# What's the population of Elantris?

Tags: cosmere, elantris

What is the total population of Elantris?

Elantris is described as a huge city, implying it should have many tens of thousands of residents. Yet, the book describes the population of Elantris as "dozens" or "hundreds", which seems odd for such a small city.

When discussing the gangs, each gang is shown to have a very small amount of people (maybe maximum a hundred each?), which implies a population of at most a few hundred, which seems very small.

What is the total population of Elantris after the fall?

Comment: In turns the city was heavily populated, then totally abandoned, then heavily populated, then decimated by famine and disease and then heavily populated once more; https://coppermind.net/wiki/Elantris_(city)

Comment: @Valorum Pretty much that, but it wasn't famine and disease - Elantrians were hit by magic failure and lots of them were killed, because of it. It's hard to say how many were left around when it was fixed.